# bash variable expansion: ${!1}, ${1#/} & usage of export and typeset without any argument

Tags: bash

I am trying to read through the bash script for rvm installation on https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/master/binscripts/rvm-installer, but I have difficulty understanding the following lines.

```
line 22: export rvm_trace_flag rvm_debug_flag rvm_user_install_flag rvm_ignore_rvmrc rvm_prefix rvm_path
```

Q: what does **export** do without any argument?

```
line 241: typeset _account _domain _pattern _repo _sources _values _version
```

Q: What does **typeset** do without any argument?

```
line 242: _sources=(${!1})
```

Q: Not sure how to interpret such variable expansion. I have already checked bash reference (http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays), still not quite get it.

```
line 510: branch=${1#/}
line 514: if [[ "${1%/}" -ne wayneeseguin ]] && [[ "${1%/}" -ne mpapis ]]
```

Q: Cannot understand these two variable expansions, either.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`export` without any argument lists all the exported variables and their definitions. Note that your line contains many arguments to `export`.

`typeset` was replaced by `declare`. Again, without arguments, it lists everything that was declared, but your example gives arguments to the command.

`${!1}` is a variable indirection. `$1` contains the name of the variable whose value will be returned:

```
test=x
set -- test
echo ${!1}   # Returns x.
```

`${1#/}` removes the `/` from the beginning of the variable `$1`, `${1%/}` removes it from the end.

See *Parameter Expansion* in `man bash` for details.

Comment: According to **Substring Removal** of [Manipulating Strings](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) -- isn't `${1%/}` removing `/` from the end?

Comment: +1, but this answer could be improved by explaining some *fishing techniques*. In other words, show OP how to use `help` and where you find these things in the manual.

Comment: What does "set -- test" do?

Comment: @zyxue: It sets `$1` to "test".

Comment: @csiu: Did I state otherwise?

Comment: @choroba: You wrote `${%1/}` instead of `${1%/}` ;)